# Create/update in mvc using EF model not working

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using an existing sql database in my MVC application. For one of the tables, the create/update functions do not work. I am assuming it is because my application fails to retrieve the auto generated ID's defined in SQL and hence inserts a null value into a non nullable field resulting in the application breaking. So, my question is how do i retrieved the auto generated fields defined in my sql database to show in my MVC5 application. Many thanks to anybody who can assist.

Below is my database table for Customers:
[image]

The Model:

```
  public partial class Customer
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Cards = new HashSet<Card>();
        this.Stores = new HashSet<Store>();
    }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int DiscountLevelID { get; set; }
    public int LoyaltyLevelID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerSurname { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string CustomerGUID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerStatus { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerTel { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCel { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerContact { get; set; }
    public string CustomerLogo { get; set; }
    public string CustomerLogoPath { get; set; }
    public int LastStoreCustomerSyncID { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CustomerID,DiscountLevelID,LoyaltyLevelID,CustomerCompanyName,CustomerName,CustomerSurname,CustomerGUID,CustomerStatus,CustomerAddress,CustomerTel,CustomerCel,CustomerNumber,CustomerContact,CustomerLogo,CustomerLogoPath,LastStoreCustomerSyncID")] Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(customer);
    }

    // GET: Companies/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(customer);
    }

    // POST: Companies/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CustomerID,DiscountLevelID,LoyaltyLevelID,CustomerCompanyName,CustomerName,CustomerSurname,CustomerGUID,CustomerStatus,CustomerAddress,CustomerTel,CustomerCel,CustomerNumber,CustomerContact,CustomerLogo,CustomerLogoPath,LastStoreCustomerSyncID")] Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(customer);
    }
```

The View

```html
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerGUID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerGUID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerGUID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the error occurred when doing `SaveChanges` to database? Which EF model used (Code First/DB First/Model First)? Include what errors found during create/update operation. Also make sure you're already set a hidden field `CustomerID` in the view.

Comment: Yes it occurs at SaveChanges. I am using db first.

Comment: What error has said there? The problem may actually happen in the DB or how you're inserting the data (have you updated the model from DB?). Also check inner exception from the error to make us sure what kind of problem you have.

Comment: It is not giving any error now but it still isn't inserting into the database :(. I did update the model from the DB

Comment: This is the error: {"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."}... {System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult}

Comment: "Validation failed for one or more entities" means that at least one required non-null field possibly empty during insertion/update. There's may have inner exception which you should looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is how do i retrieved the auto generated fields
>   defined in my sql database to show in my MVC5 application.

Follow steps

- Right click on the designer surface of the EDMX designer and click `Update Model From Database`...

All entities are refreshed by default, new entities are only added if you select them.

EDIT: If it is not refreshing well.
Select all the tables and view-s in the EDMX designer.
Delete them.
Then, update model from database

- Right click On `Model1.tt` and select '`Run Custom Tool`' save and Build Now see classes are generated.
  Right click On `Model1.Context.tt` and select '`Run Custom Tool`' save and Build Now see property IN Context class is generated like

P.S

Read this link also, it is very useful: http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/08/entity-framework-manual-update/

Answer (score 0):

You should pass CustomerID to Controller as parameter. Don't give permission to CustomerID for null values and make it AUTO_INCREMENT

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerID, new {style = 'display:none'})
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerGUID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerGUID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerGUID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```